# Как добавить несколько location для фронта и бекенда на одном домене

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

У меня есть фронт на vue.js /var/www/main-front/dist и есть бекенд /var/www/main-back/public
Нужно что бы оба проекта работали на одном домене admin.cdin.me , но запросы с перфиксом /api шли на бекенд, а без перфикса обработкой занимался фронт.

Пример текущей конфигурации nginx для обслуживания фронта и бека на одном домене.

```
server {
    server_name admin.cdin.me;
    charset utf-8;
    root /var/www/main-front/dist;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/main-back/public;
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
    }
}
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.cdin.me/fullchain.pem; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.cdin.me/privkey.pem; # Управляется Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # Управляется Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = admin.cdin.me) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # Управляется Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name admin.cdin.me;
    return 404; # Управляется Certbot
}
```

RouteServiceProvider

```
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
        });
    }
```

При попытке обратиться к эдпоинту https://admin.cdin.me/api/delete-domains

```
Route::post('/delete-domains', DeleteDomains::class);
```

Получаю ошибку

```
405 Not Allowed
```

> 2023/07/03 14:21:49 [error] 25732#25732: *374891235 FastCGI sent in
> stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from
> upstream, client:, server: admin.cdin.me, request: "POST
> /api/api/delete-domains HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.cdin.me"

Comment: `При попытке обратиться к эдпоинту https://admin-f.cdin.me/api/delete-domains` как "обращаетесь"?

Comment: curl --location 'https://admin-f.cdin.me/api/delete-domains' \
--form 'domains="asdasdamsn.com

с помощью запроса в postman, где POST запросом отправляю данные domains на указаный эндпоинт

Comment: обратимся к скучной документации и ... https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: в конфиге `server_name admin.cdin.me;` а запрос на `admin-f.cdin.me`, это как? `добавить location перфикс nginx для laravel` подробней опишите что хотите сделать

Comment: Извините, admin-f опечатка (исправил), просто скрыл оригинальное название домена. 

У меня есть фронт на vue.js /var/www/main-front/dist и есть бекенд /var/www/main-back/public

Нужно что бы оба проекта работал на домене admin.cdin.me , но запросы с перфиксом /api шли на бэкенд, а без перфикса обработкой занимался фронт

Comment: Нашел информацию в логах

2023/07/03 14:21:49 [error] 25732#25732: *374891235 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client:, server: admin.cdin.me, request: "POST /api/api/delete-domains HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.cdin.me"

Comment: `php artisan route:list` какие роуты показывает?

Comment: `POST| ban-urls  | App\Http\Controllers\BanUrls  | api  
 POST | delete-domains | App\Http\Controllers\DeleteDomains | api  
 POST | redirects-domain| App\Http\Controllers\DomainsRedirect | api  `

Comment: У вас лишняя скобка } перед error_log, возможно из-за этого.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это вложенный location для бека, он не лишний

Comment: Удалось исправить с помощью директивы rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name admin.cdin.me;

    root /var/www/main-front/dist;

    index index.html index.htm;

  
    location / {
        root /var/www/main-front/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
    }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/main-back/public;

        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    
    set $newurl $request_uri;
        if ($newurl ~ ^/api(.*)$) {
        set $newurl $1;
                root /var/www/main-back/public;
        }

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $newurl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/seo-admin-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/seo-admin-access.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.cdin.me/fullchain.pem; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.cdin.me/privkey.pem; # Управляется Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # Управляется Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # Управляется Certbot
}
```